# GRIB data interpolation

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr, d3, topojson, grib

I've been wrangling around in GFS grid based data (GRIB - mostly 0.5 degree resolution). I'm interested in plotting these by converting to geojson with ogr2ogr (which is quite easy). However, is there a best practice for interpolating the data so that the geojson is has smooth arcs? As you know, it's quite blocky. I know there's a ton of GIS software that will do this and spit out a graphic, but I'd rather have the geojson smoothed version.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check the EMOSLIB at [ECMWF software website](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/EMOS/Emoslib). It is suited for interpolations.